# "App has stopped" "Close app" android studio

Tags: java, android

ACTIVITY_MAIN.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#77dd77"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/splashIcon"
        android:layout_width="97dp"
        android:layout_height="216dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo1" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MAIN_SCREEN.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Main Screen BVOOM!"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

SCREENONE.JAVA

```
package com.example.admin.test2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ScreenOne extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);
    }
}

MAINACTIVITY.JAVA
package com.example.admin.test2;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScreenOne.class));
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

ANDROID MANIFEST

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.admin.test2">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ScreenOne">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Error from Logcat/Run tab:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.admin.test2, PID: 16184
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(144000000bytes) bitmap.
                      at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:229)
                      at android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(RecordingCanvas.java:97)
                      at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:529)
                      at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1367)
                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20370)
                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19315)
                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20093)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4421)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4207)
                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20373)
                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19315)
                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20093)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4421)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4207)
                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19306)
                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20093)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4421)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4207)
                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19306)
                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20093)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4421)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4207)
                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19306)
                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20093)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4421)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4207)
                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19306)
                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20093)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4421)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4207)
                      at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20373)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:980)
                      at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19315)
                      at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:686)
                      at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:692)
                      at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:800)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3501)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3288)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2823)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1785)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7822)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
                      at
```

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)

Application terminated.

When I build my file and emulate in my Phone Samsung Galaxy A3 2017 the app will crash and say "Test2 has stopped." "Close app" what can I do with these please help

Comment: What is unclear about this: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(144000000bytes) bitmap."

Comment: "Canvas: trying to draw too large(144000000bytes) bitmap", apparently you're trying to draw an image that is too large.

Comment: The issue are probably caused by the drawable on ImageView who are too large to be used

Answer (score 0):

Bro, In the SCREENONE.JAVA, you have, override the same method twice. Please correct it and your app your run perfectly

Comment: That's not the same activity (there is other activity named MAINACTIVITY,JAVA inside his code block)

Comment: That is clearly a formatting issue in OP's question. The two overrides reside in two different classes.